# How do I add custom DNS server and preserving default DNS of ISP in OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, dns

I'm using OS X Mountain Lion. I'm using `dnsmasq` to set up wildcard localhost domain names, such as http://local.dev, to point to localhost. But I have to add 127.0.0.1 in my system preference -> network settings.

After I set up 127.0.0.1 as the DNS server, the ISP's default DNS servers were over wrote by mine. This was preventing me from accessing websites. It's not a big deal when I don't move my computer, I could manually enter the ISP's DNS server. But if I change places, the ISP's DNS changes.

I also tried to use google's DNS server, but it's not working in some instance. How can I reserve (or update) the ISP's DNS server without deleting 127.0.0.1 as a DNS.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yep. You can do this, `/etc/resolver` is your friend.

`$ man 5 resolver`:

> domain
>   Domain name associated with this resolver configuration.
>   This option is normally not required by the Mac OS X DNS search system when the resolver configuration is read from a file in the /etc/resolver directory.   In that case the file name is used as the domain name.

Simply put you can place `nameserver 127.0.0.1` inside a file you create called `/etc/resolver/dev`

You'll need to reload/restart. It'll then direct any requests to `*.dev` to your local nameserver.

Your network connection DNS remains on automatic, so it will cope with any changes in your environment.

**Edit:** I've just found https://serverfault.com/a/164215/163311 and http://www.echoditto.com/blog/never-touch-your-local-etchosts-file-os-x-again which have a few more details and include `dnsmasq` setup details.

Comment: Second article can now be found at https://alanthing.com/blog/2012/04/24/never-touch-your-local-etchosts-file-os-x-again/

Answer (score 1):

Is there a specific reason for using [`dnsmasq`](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html)?

You could simply add entries to your [`/private/etc/hosts`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) file leaving DNS pointed to whichever ISP you happen to be connected to. Here's how to do that using Terminal:

`sudo nano /private/etc/hosts` Enter you password when prompted.

Add any additions at the end of the hosts file (a single entry per line), for example:

`127.0.0.1   local.dev`

Control + O and then enter to save the file within nano. Control + X to exit nano.

You'll than need to flush the local DNS cache using: `dscacheutil -flushcache`

Comment: Use hosts file can be a simple solution, but I need to setup wildcard domains such as *.dev to point to localhost.